# are there any odbc drivers that connect to odata or similar web data sources

Tags: odbc, odata

I want to connect using odbc to datasources I can expose over webservice like oData or a custom webservice that can accept SQL.

Are there any drivers out there that can do it?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a driver... That does not say that what you are trying to do is impossible! I believe you may need to provide more details about exactly you are trying to do here...

Comment: It seems you need RSSBUS http://www.rssbus.com/odbc/odata/ It is commercial software though, about $79 for single user.

Comment: Look at free OData API cloud server - [Skyvia Connect](https://skyvia.com/connect/). It easily exposes live cloud and database data as OData endpoint. No coding or installation needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of a provider that does this natively.

One option would be to use Entity Framework with a custom '[Entity Framework provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx)' that supports ODBC datasources and use WCF Data Services' ability to expose an Entity Framework model.

Failing that WCF Data Services also has a provider model ([see my blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx)) that allows you to write custom code to expose any datasource, be that other WebServices, Flat Files, NoSQL database or ODBC data source.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely checkout Power Query for Excel (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379).

This is a great way to export your data from oData webservices.  I tried it out on some in development services in house and it was extremely impressive... one of those WOW moments (I don't get many of these :).

Big caveat is that you can't import using PowerQuery (and please point out if I'm wrong here... I'd love to use it for import!).

I also came across the http://www.rssbus.com/odbc/odata/ solution (now up to $99/client) and will try this out for an import solution.

Comment: I agree that RSSBus (http://www.rssbus.com/odbc/odata/default.aspx) is probably your best bet. I use their Quickbooks Connector (http://www.rssbus.com/odata/quickbooks/integration.aspx). With that product, I am able to access/import Quickbooks ("QB") data using Power Query for Excel using the OData Feed option. I believe that product connects to QB via ODBC. I am also able to set-up data replication from QB to an Access DB (or any other DB) from within the RSSBus product.